# How to implement a deep copy of an object that contains an array of objects in Java?

Tags: java, clone

I need to make a class called `Garage` implement `Cloneable` and override the `Object.clone()` method to make a deep copy of an object of type `Garage` which contains an array of objects of type `Vehicle`.

I have read on several SO answers that `Cloneable` is broken and it is wise not to use it, but my lab assignment demands that I implement `Cloneable` and code a proper `clone()` method. I have been looking for long but still haven't been able to do this. Any help would be much appreciated.

This is my code for the `Garage` class:

```
public class Garage extends Vehicle implements Cloneable {
    // array to store up to 15 Vehicle objects
    Vehicle array[] = new Vehicle[15];

    // overriding the clone method to perform a deeper copy
    @Override
    protected Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        //TODO
    }
}
```

This is my code for the `Vehicle` class:

```
public class Vehicle {
    int numWheels;
    int ID;
    String name;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all `Garage extends Vehicle` makes no sense. I'm assuming it's a mistake. A `Garage` is **not** a `Vehicle`.

In `Garage` you can implement `clone` as :

```
@Override
protected Object clone() {
    Garage other = new Garage ();
    for (Vehicle v : this.array) {
        other.addVehicle((Vehicle)v.clone());
    }
    return other;
}
```

Then you have to implement `clone()` in the `Vehicle` class hierarchy.

Comment: How should I then implement the addVehicle() method? The addVehicle method should add a Vehicle to the array of the Garage object, for which we need to pass a Vehicle to this method, but the line of code inside your for loop is passing an Object, not a Vehicle. It's giving me a type mismatch.

Comment: @AkshayDamle Sorry about that. You should cast the result of the clone to the required type. Edited my answer.

Comment: The better way is to get the object with `super.clone()` rather than `new Garage()`; the former will work with subclasses that inherit this method, the latter will not.

Comment: @newacct I assumed that Garage shouldn't be a sub-class of Vehicle (since it makes no sense), so there is no super.clone(). Even if there was, you wouldn't want to get the instance from the super class, since that would give you an instance of the super class. In that case I would split the cloning to two methods - one would just create an instance of the cloned object and call the other method, which would clone the members. The first one would be overridden by each class. The second would be overridden by each class, but would also call its super-class implementation.

Comment: @Eran: No, there is always a `super.clone()`, because there is `Object.clone()`. And the *point* of `Object.clone()` is that it gives you an instance of the *same class* as the object, whatever the class is. This you cannot do with `new Whatever`.

Comment: @newacct Thanks, I wasn't aware of that. We do it differently (as I mentioned in my previous comment) where I work. Now, after reading about how Object.clone() is supposed to be used, and why it is [broken](http://www.artima.com/intv/bloch13.html), I see why we don't use it this way.